# OpenCV2 window freezing and closing as program starts

Tags: python, opencv, facial-identification

I am creating a facial recognition program for my university project after making the code and running it I get no errors however when the webcam opens the image is frozen and the window closes code is below

```
import face_recognition
import os, sys
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math


def face_confidence(face_distance, face_match_threshold=0.6):
    range = (1.0 - face_match_threshold)
    linear_val = (1.0 - face_distance) / (range * 2.0)

    if face_distance > face_match_threshold:
        return str(round(linear_val * 100, 2)) + '%'
    else:
        value = (linear_val +((1.0 - linear_val) * math.pow((linear_val - 0.5) * 2, 0.2))) * 100
        return str(round(value, 2)) + '%'

class FaceRecognition:

    face_locations = []
    face_encoding = []
    face_names =[]
    known_face_encodings = []
    known_face_names = []
    process_current_frame = True

    def __init__(self):
        self.encode_faces()



    def encode_faces(self):
        for image in os.listdir("Faces"):
            face_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(f'faces/{image}')
            face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(face_image) [0]

            self.known_face_encodings.append(face_encoding)
            self.known_face_names.append(image)

        print(self.known_face_names)

    def run_recognition(self):
        video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        if not video_capture.isOpened():
            sys.exit('video source not found')

        while True:
            ret, frame = video_capture.read()

            if self.process_current_frame:
                small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0, 0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)
                rgb_small_frame = small_frame[:, :, ::-1]

                #find all faces in current frame
                self.face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_small_frame)
                self.face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_small_frame, self.face_locations)

                self.face_names = []
                for face_encoding in self.face_encodings:
                    matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(self.known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
                    name = 'unknown'
                    confidence ='unknown'

                    face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(self.known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
                    best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)

                    if matches[best_match_index]:
                        name = self.known_face_names[best_match_index]
                        confidence = face_confidence(face_distances[best_match_index])

                    self.face_names.append(f'{name}: ({confidence})')

                self.process_current_frame = not self.process_current_frame

                #display annotations

                for(top,right,bottom,left), name in zip(self.face_locations, self.face_names):
                    top *= 4
                    right *= 4
                    bottom *= 4
                    left *= 4

                    cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0,0,25), 2)
                    cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 25), -1)
                    cv2.putText(frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (255, 255, 255), 1)

                cv2.imshow('Face Recognition', frame)

                if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
                    break

            video_capture.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fr = FaceRecognition()
    fr.run_recognition()
```

I understand that `cv2.destroyAllWindows()` is what's responsible for the window closing however im struggling to figure why its doing it straight away. after removing that line of code to try and test it further my window stays open but the window crashes and showing its not responding. any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: You have `video_capture.release()` and `cv2.destroyAllWindows()` inside of your while-loop.  Those should be outside of it.  Right now it runs the code in the while loop once, then releases the web cam and closes the window.

Comment: I don't know how i missed that thank you I moved it over now however I still have an issue with the application crashing. I moved over 'cv2.imshow('Face Recognition', frame)' back an indent located near the bottom of the code which fixes the window from crashing but with that done the box to locate the face is not showing up.